# Autocomplete (Intellisense) does not work properly for Python in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I am using VSCode for Python development working in a Dev-Container. Python is installed inside the dev-container and the Python executable path in the settings.json file is correct.

However, when I import numpy via "import numpy as np" in some module I am writing and start typing "np.", the pop-up window will only display some of the methods that the numpy module offers. E.g., if I start typing "np.a", the abs-method is not displayed in the pop-up windows. In general, it seems like most of the methods are missing.

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Just to be sure: The Python extension (ms-python.python) is installed in VSCode, and numpy is installed, too? A script containing only `import numpy` `numpy.abs(1)` runs fine?

Comment: Yes, numpy is specified in the install_requires list of the package under development and the package under development is installed via pip.

Comment: What about the extension and running the script?

Comment: The extension is installed and running the script works fine. Excuse my incomplete answer!

Comment: No worries :) I can't reproduce your issue with a regular installation. What kind of dev-container are you running?

Comment: Are you sure you have the right environment selected in the extension? Check the status bar to make sure the path matches the environment you installed into.